# How do I refer to the input values within a table cell for looped validation?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table with repeated rows of input similar to the following:

```
<table id="tableInput">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id='abc'>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="itemid" name="itemid"  type="text" size="20" /></td>
    <td>Col2 desc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="itemid" name="itemid"  type="text" size="20" /></td>
    <td>Col2 desc</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I reference the input id's in a validation loop?  Something like:

```
i=0;
while i < document.getElementById("tableInput").tBodies.length {
  x = document.getElementById("tableInput").tBodies[i].input.value);
  if x = "" {
      errorMsg = 1;
  }
 i++;
 }
```

Comment: The `id` attribute of each `<input>` should be unique.

Comment: Is this pseudo code or a dialect or did you just forget the `(...)` around the conditions?

Comment: `FormElement.elements` collection will contain an Array Like Object you can loop over for all of your inputs within a `<form>` if you're using one, without the `id`. Another solution could be `document.getElementsByTagName('input')`.

Comment: @PHPglue - he has no form element here, it's not that trivial.

Answer (score 0):

The ID of an element has to be unique.

```
<input id="itemid" name="itemid"  type="text" size="20" />
```

So in each row you want a different value for `itemid`. Secondly check you if-statement. Parentheses are missing and you assing a value to x instead of comparing it.

For the loop you can use `getElementByTagName` (see vsync's answer)

Answer (score 0):

What Felix said is true, the `id` **must** be unique. (you can also remove it if you don't use it)

But try this to loop on all the inputs inside `tableInput`.

```
var scope = document.getElementById('#tableInput');
var inputs = scope.getElementsByTagName('input');

// traverse on all the input elements inside "tableInput"
for( var i = inputs.length; i--; ){
  // if some input has no value then..
  if( !inputs[i].value ){
    errorMsg = 1;
    // inputs[i].id  // access the ID
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try something like:

```
var ipts = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), inVals = [], errors = [];
for(var i=0,l=ipts.length; i<l; i++){
  var ip = ipts[i];
  if(ip.type === 'text'){
    inVals.push(ip.value);
  }
}
for(var i in inVals){
  if(inVals[i] === ''){
    errors[i] = 'required error';
  }
}
```

`errors[4]` would contain `'required error'` if `inVals[4]` is `''`. That's the logic, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to do. You can get all the controls in a form using its [*elements*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-form-elements) collection, e.g.

```
var form = document.getElementById('tableInput');
var controls = form.elements;
for (var i=0, iLen=controls.length; i<iLen; i++) {

  // do stuff with controls[i]

  // to do stuff with just input elements
  if (controls[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input') {
    console.log(controls[i].name);
  }

  // and so on…

}
```

As noted above, element ids *should* be unique, but nothing drastic happens if they aren't. It just makes *getElementById* a bit useless. But form controls should rarely need an id since they must have a name to be successful and can be accessed by that.

Note that the above works regardless of the structure of the document, whether some are in a table and others not, or even if the controls are actually in the form (as long as they are associated with the form using the [*form*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#attr-fae-form) attribute). Controls in the form have their *form* property set automatically to the form they're in.